# How to modify the table of content (centralizing the content title and adding a short text on top of that )

Tags: table-of-contents

In the sequence of my question ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680150/how-to-modify-the-table-of-content-part-1)), this is the third part. I want to centralize the title of "Content" and add a short text on top of it like the following figure, but I don't know how to do it. Thanks. Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\linespread{1.5}



\begin{document}


\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{ \textbf{Title}  \hfill  \textbf{Page}\par}



\chapter{Spring}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp1}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp2}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp3}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp4}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp5}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp6}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp7}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp8}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Sp9}\lipsum[1-30]  

\chapter{Summer}
\section{Su1}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su2}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su3}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su4}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su5}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su6}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su7}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su8}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{Su9}\lipsum[1-30]  

\chapter{Fall}
\section{F1}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F2}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F3}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F4}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F5}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F6}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F7}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F8}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{F9}\lipsum[1-30]   

\chapter{Winter}
\section{W1}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W2}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W3}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W4}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W5}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W6}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W7}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W8}\lipsum[1-30]
\section{W9}\lipsum[1-30]   

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make all your question self-sustained. They should be understandable without having to read your whole series of questions. In particular, add a MWE which is adapted to the current problem, to all your questions, not only to the first one.

Comment: I have modified the question, thanks.

Comment: Why does a MWE about adding a header require sooooooooooooooooooooo many sections?

Comment: Please also edit your questions titles to reflect what they are actually about. In their current form, future users with the same problem are unlikely to find your question.

Comment: The table of contents is a chapter so: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13496/center-aligning-chapters for the centering. But preambles on top or below a chapter headings would be provided, e.g., by the KOMA-Script classes, that also provide `\raggedchapter`, that could be redefined to be `\centering`.

Comment: Dear @cabohah, thanks for you help but I only need to change the content title not all chapters.

Comment: You can use `\titleformat` more than once and also the KOMA-Script suggestion wouldn't be possible to change only the heading of the table of contents.

Comment: Dear @cabohah, if you provide the right MWE, it would be kind of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already told in a comment, KOMA-Script classes provide `\raggedchapter` to change the alignment of the chapter headings and `\setchapterpreamble` to place a preamble text on top of below a chapter headings. So you can change the alignment before (and after) the table of contents and add a preamble. As an extra feature it provides `\BeforeTOCHead`. This can be used to do all the relevant changes from within the document preamble, without changing the headings of other chapters:

```
\documentclass[emulatestandardclasses,a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \let\raggedchapter\centering
  \setchapterpreamble[o]{\centering\color{red} a short text}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image: Table of contents with centered heading an preamble text above the heading]

With the standard classes also the `\BeforeTOC` feature of KOMA-Script could be used. To do so, you can load package `tocbasic`. However the preamble feature would still not be available, so you need a ugly hack to add the text on top of the heading, e.g., a local redefinition of `\contentsname`. But in this case you would also need to change the marks for the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{%
  \let\raggedchapter\centering
  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}%
  \renewcommand*{\contentsname}{% Ugly hack to add preamble and to center
    \centering
    \textcolor{red}{\normalsize a short text}\par
    Contents
  }%
}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{%
  \markboth{CONTENTS}{CONTENTS}%
}

\begin{document}

\listoftoc[\contentsname]{toc}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @cabohah, thanks for your answer, but what shall I do for the `book` document class?

Comment: @AYBRXQD Why using a class, that does not provide what you want? Using a class, which does provide most of the wanted features, is more comfortable and smarter.